# How come this python class prints out my kwargs?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Meta(dict):
    def __init__(self, indexed, method, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Meta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print self
```

How come this prints my kwargs?

```
m = Meta(indexed='hello', method='distance', a='3', b='4')
```

When I run this, it prints out a dictionary with my kwargs, when I'm expecting an empty dictionary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `dict` class initializes its contents from the keyword arguments passed to its constructor:

```
>>> dict(indexed='hello', method='distance', a='3', b='4')
{'a': '3', 'indexed': 'hello', 'b': '4', 'method': 'distance'}
```

Since your class calls `dict`'s constructor with the keyword arguments passed to its own constructor, the dictionary is indeed initialized and the same behavior is observed.

Answer (score 4):

*Why* do you expect self not to contain your keyword args, when you explicitly initialized your instance (a dict subclass) with the keyword args by calling the dict class's initializer?

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't it? The class inherits the related **str** and **repr** implementation from dict.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `print self` in the constructor is effectively printing your kwargs.  This is because of the behavior you inherited from the dict class.  The kwargs are included in the dictionary store.

```
>>> d = dict(a=3, b=4)
>>> print d
{'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your are passing them to the initializer of dict.

try that:

```
>>> dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```